# Compress and Decompress String in Java

Tags: java, compression

I'm trying to compress and decompress a string from producer and consumer environment (which accepts only string as params).

So after I compress a string, I'm converting compressed byte array to string and then passing it to producer. 
Then in consumer part, I'm taking the string back , converting into byte array and then decompressing the string from bytes.

Instead of converting into string, if I used byte[], then it is working fine. But what I need is to convert into string and viceversa.

Here is my code :

```
public class Compression {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String strToCompress = "Helloo!! ";
    byte[] compressedBytes = compress(strToCompress);

    String compressedStr = new String(compressedBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    byte[] bytesToDecompress = compressedStr.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    String decompressedStr = decompress(bytesToDecompress);

    System.out.println("Compressed Bytes : "+Arrays.toString(compressedBytes));

    System.out.println("Decompressed String : "+decompressedStr);

}

public static byte[] compress(final String str) throws IOException {
    if ((str == null) || (str.length() == 0)) {
      return null;
    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream obj = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(obj);
    gzip.write(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    gzip.flush();
    gzip.close();
    return obj.toByteArray();
  }

  public static String decompress(final byte[] compressed) throws IOException {
    final StringBuilder outStr = new StringBuilder();
    if ((compressed == null) || (compressed.length == 0)) {
      return "";
    }
    if (isCompressed(compressed)) {   //It is not going into this if part
      final GZIPInputStream gis = new GZIPInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(compressed));
      final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(gis, "UTF-8"));

      String line;
      while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        outStr.append(line);
      }
    } else {
      outStr.append(compressed);
    }
    return outStr.toString();
  }

  public static boolean isCompressed(final byte[] compressed) {
    return (compressed[0] == (byte) (GZIPInputStream.GZIP_MAGIC)) && (compressed[1] == (byte) (GZIPInputStream.GZIP_MAGIC >> 8));
  }

}
```

Comment: So what is the problem? (What do you expect vs. what happens)

Comment: Do consumer and producer run in different virutal machines? How do they communicate? Via network or on the same machine via pipes?

Comment: I removed the Kafka tag, but Kafka can accept bytes, not only strings. Plus, it can perform compression for you as part of the Producer API

Comment: @isnot2bad After converting into compressed string, I can't decompress it back from compressedString from compressedString.getBytes[]. It gives isCompressed as false.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assume a compressed string can be treated as UTF-8 as many possible byte combinations are not valid UTF-8.  I suggest trying ISO-8859-1 which keeps all 8-bit values untranslated.

Also note that while large pieces of text should get smaller, small strings can get larger.

Note: This loop will strip any newline characters

```
  String line;
  while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    outStr.append(line);
  }
```

I suggest instead copying using a `char[]` which won't drop any characters.

```
 char[] chars = new char[512];
 for(int len; (len = reader.read(chars)) > 0;)
     outStr.append(chars, 0, len);
```